# How to display data from dispatch method inside map loop in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table and in each row I'm displaying  'Monthly paymnent' which I get from server . I paste my dispatch method  in render function and throws me error 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.' What is best way to render response from async method without storing it in state

```
                   loans.map((loan, ids) => {
                      return loan.ratesList.map((rateItem, rateIdx) => {
                        return (
                        
                            <TableCell>
                              <p className="secondaryText ">
                                Monthly payment
                              </p>
                              <p className="highlightText">
                                {dispatch(
                                  getMonthlyPayment({
                                    initialFeeSum:
                                      mortgageProgramParams.initialFeeSum,
                                    monthsCount: 180,
                                    rateId: rateItem.id,
                                    valueSum: mortgageProgramParams.valueSum,
                                  })
                                )}
                              </p>
                            </TableCell>                        
                        );
                      });
                    });
```

dispatch method

```
export const getMonthlyPayment = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  return api
    .post(`loanCalculator/calculation`, data)
    .then((res) => {
      const { data } = res;
      return data.monthlyPayment;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is an anti pattern IMHO. Consider you have an value which will be [] initally but will be changed to [ {}, {} ] once you have made the API call now you are clearly changing the value from its previous state .

State in react exists for this purpose . To hold values which changes over time . Also you need to re-render your component once you get the response from the API call and the only way to  trigger a re-render in this case is having a state and updating it .

So it's always good to have your API response in state .

Comment: If I have a dozen of requests , I can't store all of them in state.

Comment: But you can wait for all of them to complete . You can fire parallel requests and await for them using Promise.all